# Immutable Method in Java

Tags: java, immutability, const, final

In Java, there is the `final` keyword in lieu of the `const` keyword in C and C++.

In the latter languages there are mutable and immutable methods such as stated in [the answer by Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455535/40342) to the question [How many and which are the uses of “const” in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c)

> Use const to tell others methods won't change the logical state of this object.
>
> ```
> struct SmartPtr {
>     int getCopies() const { return mCopiesMade; }
> }ptr1;
>
> ...
>
> int var = ptr.getCopies(); // returns mCopiesMade and is specified that to not modify objects state.
> ```

How is this performed in Java?

Comment: Note that D language allows the following syntax: `int getA(POD o) pure nothrow {
  return o.a;
}` which is very cool, IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. I'm not familiar with Java 7, but at least in Java 6 you cannot tell the compiler a method is not supposed to mutate its arguments or the `this` instance.

Unfortunately `final` in Java doesn't mean the same as `const` in C++.

A `final` argument means something else: merely that you cannot reassign it, so that the following is an error:

```
A method(final B arg) {
    ...
    arg = something;  // error, since arg is final
    ...
}
```

This is a good practice, but it won't prevent you from mutating `arg` by calling one of its methods.

A `final` method such as `final A method(...)` is related to subclassing rules, and not with mutation.

Comment: Thank you! I can't remember how, with in C, informing the compiler it won't mutate it's arguments will speed or optimize the program; that can be researched on my own. Even with, in your example, variable arg of type B being final, there is no optimization -- Is this because the program is compiled and then interpreted towards the platform running the program?

Comment: @ChrisOkyen: Java demands more from its compiler and runtime. For example if the runtime wants to optimize that methods *it* should figure out if the method mutates any fields (and it can!). Also note that the compiler (`javac`) does little to no optimization in Java, that's left to the JVM (runtime).

Comment: "This is a good practice, but it won't prevent you from mutating arg by calling one of its methods.": In C++ if you have an argument of type const boost::shared_ptr<T>& you cannot change the pointer, but you can still change the object, if the object has non `const` methods.

Comment: @Giorgio Thanks, good point. I'm a bit rusty with my C++ :)

Comment: @Giorgio true, it is easy to mix up immutable const reference/pointer with a variable who's value is not mutable.

Answer (score 5):

Java's `final` is not in lieu of C's `const`. In Java `final` may appear in five places. Attribute, variable and formal parameter declarations and class and method definitions. Using `final` for attributes, variables or parameters means, you cannot reassign them, so the following will not be accepted by the compiler:

```
final List<String> xs = new ArrayList<>();
xs = new LinkedList<>(); //illegal
```

However, note that you can still change the object referenced by `xs`:

```
final List<String> xs = new ArrayList<>();
xs.add("Hello World");
```

As for classes, `final` forbids inheriting from this class. So, this is illegal too:

```
final class A {
}

class B extends A { //illegal
}
```

And for methods `final` forbids overriding the method in a subclass, thus the following is illegal.

```
class A {
    final void m() {}
}

class B extends A {
    final void m() { System.exit(1); } //illegal
}
```

So why would anyone use one keyword for three different intentions? Well, they are connected. If you take a look at `java.lang.String` you will see, that it is declared as `final`. And since there are not operations in `String` that will change the value of the instance you can safely assume that

```
final String GREETING = "Hello, World!";
```

defines a constant.

BTW, `const` is a reserved word in Java, too. But it has no semantics and thus cannot be used in any Java program.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can make a Java object immutable is from within the class of that object itself and not from other calling classes.

You may only have **constant pointer** (final reference by the official Java name) meaning that you cannot modify the reference to point to another object; you cannot have **pointer to constant**, meaning you cannot modify the referring object, as you may have in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to create const method in Java is to create a const interface for the object. Like:

```
interface ConstSomething {
    int getCopies();
}
class Something implements ConstSomething {
    int getCopies() { return mCopiesMade; }
}
```

Yes, unlike C++ `const` this affects performance, because now the method has to be called virtually.

Note, that the same applies to C#.

Comment: You are saying that becuase it can't tell the compiler that the method will not modify the objects state affects performance? Why does it have to be called virtually?

Comment: @ChrisOkyen: Because you can't tell the compiler that the method will not modify the objects state you have to call it on an interface if you want to do that anyway. But if you call it on an interface, the compiler does not know the actual type and can't call the method non-virtually. Plus of course it can't do any optimization based on that promise if you can't tell it (because `const` in C++ only applies to that reference, the room for optimization based on it is rather limited anyway).

Comment: I am not 100 percent clear on how using an inteface and not knwoing the type relates becuase I don't fully understand how in C++ such a method optimizes.. I don't understand the virtual or non virtual thing? Are you speaking of the OOP term virtual like virtual methods or classes in C++? I don't remember much about it, it's been nearly 10 years since I first learned the fundamentals of C++ and OOP, and been at least 4 or 5 since I used it on a regularly basis.... How does it relate to optimization.. maybe this goes out of the q.'s scope....

Comment: @ChrisOkyen: In Java all methods are virtual (called based on runtime type), but when the compiler can prove the method won't be overridden (the class or method are final), it calls the implementation directly without consulting the instance metadata, which is faster. C++ `const` does not interfere with this, but creating a read-only interface does, because interface methods can't be final.